# Virtual Accelerometer in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I've seen many tutorials about how to use a smartphone's accelerometer as input to control an object in Unity, but is possible to simulate a tri-axial accelerometer in Unity itself?

Comment: Do you want to get the acceleration of an object in Unity, or IRL?

Comment: An object in Unity @DanielGeyfman

Comment: An object's ```transform.up``` is your source of truth, just ```.Dot()``` it against the world axes you're interested in.

Comment: @Immersive but [`acceleration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html) is not the same as a gyroscope, right? @OP what exactly do you mean? The local or global movement of an object? -> simply keep track of its position in the last frame and compare it to the current one

Comment: @derHugo, traditionally an accelerometer is used to track phone orientation as it 'just works' due to gravity, whereas gyroscopes require some initialisation and calibration steps.  But that's for rotational 3DOF.  If OP wants translation as well, that's obviously a bit different.

Comment: I read the OP as wanting to emulate a tilt plane, roll ball game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can essentially get the "acceleration"(a.k.a the velocity) of an object by dividing the distance covered over time. In this case, that means breaking up a Vector3 into individual xyz variables, then calculating speed on each, and putting them back into a Vector3.

Code:

```js
Vector3 lastPos;

void Start() {
  lastPos = transform.position;
}

void Update() {
  // define velocities as currentPos-lastPos(change) over time per frame, which gets velocity this frame... will be saved every frame
  float xVelocity = (transform.position.x-lastPos.x)/Time.deltaTime;
  float yVelocity = (transform.position.y-lastPos.y)/Time.deltaTime;
  float zVelocity = (transform.position.z-lastPos.z)/Time.deltaTime;
  
  // Do stuff with individual velocities(xyz)
  // ...
  // or store in Vector3
  Vector3 totalVelocity = new Vector3(xVelocity, yVelocity, zVelocity);
  // Do stuff with total velocity
  // ...

  // Set lastPos to transform.position (WARNING: Only do after you are done calculating velocity
  
  lastPos = transform.position;
}
```